# Retrieving folder contents in Azure git

Tags: git, azure, file, path

For Azure git, I am able to retrieve the contents of a file in the browser using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source%20providers/get%20file%20contents?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{Project}/_apis/sourceProviders/TfsGit/filecontents?repository={repo}&path={filename}&commitOrBranch=master&api-version=5.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7BProject%7D/_apis/sourceProviders/TfsGit/filecontents?repository=%7Brepo%7D&path=%7Bfilename%7D&commitOrBranch=master&api-version=5.0-preview.1)

But when I call a similar command that should list all files in a directory, [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source%20providers/get%20path%20contents?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) doesn't work:
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{Project}/_apis/sourceProviders/TfsGit/pathcontents?repository={repo}&path={foldername}&commitOrBranch=master&api-version=5.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7BProject%7D/_apis/sourceProviders/TfsGit/pathcontents?repository=%7Brepo%7D&path=%7Bfoldername%7D&commitOrBranch=master&api-version=5.0-preview.1)

It always returns this:

```
{"count":0,"value":[]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try api version 6.1-preview.1, other than that I'm of little help. I went down this rabbit hole on the Git provider side, got the same result, and when I looked at the providers list API, found that TfsGit allegedly supports pathcontents, where the Git provider does not!

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately 6.1-preview.1 gives the same result.